# Determining if a 3D function is 1-1 and/or onto?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say you have a function:

$$z=7x+4y$$
where x,y,z are integers.

Now, I'd suppose that this would graph a <strike>straight line through the xyz plane</strike> 3-dimensional plane. This would be a defined function that **is not 1-1** since we have two independent variables (x,y) mapping to the same dependent variable (z)?

It does seem to be onto as well.

Can we 'patch' this function by restricting the domain to make it 1-1 and/or onto?

Comment: As a function $z=f(x,y)$ from the pairs $(x,y)$ of integers into the integers, this function is onto but not 1-1.

Comment: If you mean the set of points $(x,y, 7x+4y)$ into $\mathbb R^3$, then this set of points is a plane. A plane is not onto $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Well, I simply mean a function z defined by $7x+4y$. I do not know what you mean by 'into' R^3 (note that I am not familiar with 3D systems at this point in my career, hence the question, heh)

Comment: The graph of $y=ax+b$ is a straight line, but the graph of $z=ax+by+c$ is not a straight line. It's a plane. If your web browser supports WebGL, you can see the graph of $z=7x+4y$ here: https://www.google.com/search?q=z%3D7x%2B4y

Comment: @Bob: Sorry, I gave a reply that I think is better-adapted to your question.

Comment: I see. It seems like knowing that this results in a plane would be very helpful when approaching this problem without any calculator or grapher.

Answer (score 0):

Think carefully about how this function would look: This is actually a graph of a plane, not a line. And so it is not 1-1 because for a given z, say z=28, any ordered pair that satisfies 28 = 7x + 4y will return z=28.

Comment: Ah, so it is NOT 1-1 since we have two values of the domain mapping to the same value in the range?

Comment: You have actually, infinitely-many pairs $(x,y)$ mapping to the same $z$

Comment: What if we restrict the domain of x and y to just integers? Can we 'patch' the domain to make it 1-1?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $7x+4y= 7(x-4k)+4(y+7k)$.....   . Now sub in $k=0,1.2,....$.